# TP-Link drivers on Raspberry Pi 2 Raspberry Pi OS

Tags: linux-kernel, wifi

I have recently acquired a TP-Link 300 Mbps Mini Wireless N USB Adapter (Ver 3.0).

Naively I had hoped that using this wireless adapter with my Raspberry Pi would be a simple matter, but this was not the case. I've now been told that downloading the linux kernel, then modifying it, compiling it, and installing it is normal for wireless adapter driver installation. The drivers along with installation instructions can be found here: https://www.tp-link.com/au/support/download/tl-wn823n/.
I decided to use the "beta" version for linux. The download comes with installation instructions included in the zip file.

The main reason I come here is that the installation instructions as written state a requirement of the Raspberry Pi 3, and an older operating system from when the main operating system was still called Raspbian, instead of Raspberry Pi OS. I would like to know if I should still follow these instructions as written, or if there are tweaks I need to make. I'm also confused about how I'm supposed to check the kernel, as it says, to see if I can skip a step, and also what exact portion of it is the step I could skip.

While I'm at it, maybe I should ask whether this will even be useful for what I want to use it for. I'm planning on trying to run dsniff and aircrack-ng tools from the Raspberry Pi for my university topic. If there's any specific option or command or setting I'll need to enable to do that, please let me know. If this won't work at all, let me know what sort of adapter I should get, or if I should just give up and get one of the Raspberry Pis with a builtin wifi card or something.

Comment: Are you aware of [raspberrypi.se] ?

Comment: Also from your link "Operating System: Linux (kernel 2.6.18 ~ 3.10.10)".: chances are this won't work anymore on newer kernels. Here's a random link that might help: https://forum.puppylinux.com/viewtopic.php?t=8151 . With some chance you are just missing the firmware package (firmware-realtek).

Comment: found a git repo with instructions, got it all working, will write up a self answer when i get the energy and such.